# KSoap String Result to Date in Android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

here is my KSoap result. when i called its getProperty(0) then gives below output.

`result.getProperty(0)`

> [[1], [2013-06-21 00:00:00.0]]

now i need to get only its' date section

eg : 2013-06-21 00:00:00.0

please advice me to do that .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an array to me. What if you parse the property to an array, and get the 2nd object?

Comment: I dont have an example here, so can't help you with the array sample code right now. But what if you debug through the code, and check what kind of type the result.getProperty(0) returns? You can check it with object.getClass().getName()